# Some keyboard keys are not working with Ubuntu 20.04 on my Lenovo X1 Carbon

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, lenovo, keyboard-layout, thinkpad

I found that some keys (e.g. <kbd>g</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>Up arrow</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>) are not working fine. Sometimes they stop working and I have to go to another app and press mouse keys to get them running again.

I have tested the hardware with the `showkey` command and keys were sending the code properly. It means hardware is not an issue.

Also I have tried to use the below command to configure the suitable keyboard, but was not able to find one:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Also, my external keyboard is working fine.

**I have changed my OS to 20.04. But it is still not working.**

How to solve this? Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I also noticed that it was working fine for some hour after installing the Ubuntu 20.04. And suddenly these keys stopped working.

Comment: How did you changed your OS to 20.04? Reinstalling or Some manual file changes?